# Unable to apply coefficient of Kaiser window in C++ visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio-2010, filter, lowpass-filter

I am trying to pass my data through a low pass filter having cutoff frequency 1 Hz in C++. For this I design a kaiser window through Matlab and get 20 coefficients. here is my Matlab code:-

```
fc = 1; % cutoff frequency 1 Hz
Wn = (2/Fs)*fc;
b = fir1(20,Wn,'low',kaiser(21,3));
```

To try to understand how to apply this filter using C++, I am using [this link](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/fp/Definition_Simplest_Low_Pass.html) for an example of applying a Low Pass Filter. Here is the code given in the link.

```
/* C function implementing the simplest lowpass:
 * 
 *      y(n) = x(n) + x(n-1)
 *
 */
double simplp (double *x, double *y, 
               int M, double xm1)
{
  int n;
  y[0] = x[0] + xm1;
  for (n=1; n < M ; n++) {
    y[n] =  x[n]  + x[n-1];
  }
  return x[M-1];
}
```

but I still don't understand know how to apply the coefficients of the matlab filter. So, please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The example C++ code shows how to apply a filter that has 2 coefficients, both equal to 1.0. But you have 20 coefficients, each with a different value. Steps you need to take:

### Create Coefficent Array

Create a coefficient array, containing the coefficients you got from matlab. The code for this would look something like:

```
static const std::size_t coefCount = 20;
static const double coefs[coefCount] =
{
    0.123, 0.234, 0.345, 0.456, 0.567,
    0.678, 0.789, 0.890, 0.901, 0.012,
    0.123, 0.234, 0.345, 0.456, 0.567,
    0.678, 0.789, 0.890, 0.901, 0.012
};
```

except of course you would use the coefficients produced by matlab.

### Apply the coefficients

Within your function, apply these coefficients to the input data, producing output data. Applying the coefficients means convolving them with the input data. The main loop would look something like:

```
std::size_t outputIndex = 0;
for (std::size_t inputIndex = coefCount - 1; inputIndex < inputCount; inputIndex++)
{
    output[outputIndex] = 0.0;
    for (std::size_t coefIndex = 0; coefIndex < coefCount; coefIndex++)
        output[outputIndex] += input[inputIndex - coefIndex] * coefficient[coefIndex];
    outputIndex++;
}
```

### Deal with Start and End of Data

Decide how to deal with the beginning (and end) of the input data. You'll notice that the main loop example I gave only produced `inputCount - coefCount + 1` output samples. This may be sufficient for what you're doing - or it may not.

If you assume that the input data is a single chunk of a larger stream of input data, and you want to process multiple contiguous chunks of input data to produce multiple contiguous chunks of output data, then you need to pass some of the previous input chunk into the function. This previous input data is used when computing the first `coefCount - 1` output samples. Your example `simplp` function does this, by passing in a single `xm1` value. But you would need to pass in an array of `coefCount - 1` values.

The code to apply the initial data gets slightly more complicated, so I will leave it as an exercise for the reader. :)

The `simplp` function also passes back the last input value as a return value. If you really want to emulate `simplp`, you would pass back an array of the last `coefCount - 1` input values. You don't want to actually pass back a separate array (inefficient and unnecessary) but you might want to pass back a pointer to these last `coefCount - 1` values.